# Unable to get signed URL from Amazon-S3 in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My goal is to download a PDF file, which I have saved in my Amazon S3 bucket.
[image]
As you can see in the following code snippets, whenever makes a GET request to /api/download, I am sending back the url to the client.

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const downloadRoutes = require("./routes/downloadRoutes");

const app = express();

app.use("/api/download", downloadRoutes);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 5000");
});
```

routes/downloadRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyID: process.env.AMAZON_ACESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  s3.getSignedUrl(
    "getObject",
    {
      Bucket: "download-hemanta-cv",
      ContentType: "application/pdf",
      Key: "CV_Hemanta_Sundaray.pdf",
    },
    (err, url) => {
      res.send(url);
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, when I making a request to the above mentioned route in POSTMAN, I am not getting any response. I should be getting back the signed URL from Amazon S3. However, the status code is 200 OK & there are  no errors.
[image]

I can't figure out the problem. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things:

- It should be `ResponseContentType` than `ContentType` or we can ignore this.
- it is returning 200 Ok because `res.send(url)` is called incase of success and error.

here is the modified method:

```
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  s3.getSignedUrl(
    "getObject",
    {
      Bucket: "download-hemanta-cv",
      ResponseContentType: "application/pdf",
      Key: "CV_Hemanta_Sundaray.pdf",
    },
    (err, url) => {
      console.log("error", err, "url", url);
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        res.send(url);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Hi @Balu. Thanks a lot. Now that I have the URL at the client side, how do I download the file? There will be a button at the frontend and when someone clicks on the button, the file should be automatically downloaded. How do I handle this?

Comment: Great! and for downloading, we simply need to do a GET call of that url , that will return the file bytes. if its a picture we can directly use in `src` in `img` tag to show on UI

Comment: I have run into a problem. Can you please take a look at the following question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330940/unable-to-access-pdf-file-in-amazon-s3-bucket-through-presigned-url

Comment: I got an error. Can you please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333523/unable-to-load-the-file-by-loading-the-presignedurl-in-the-browser

Comment: @hemanta can you please upvote and/or accept answers, if these solved the issue.