# Unable to access PDF file in Amazon S3 bucket through presigned URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am learning to download files from Amazon S3 using React and Node. The idea is that when I click on a download button at the client-side, the file download should automatically start. Until now, I have managed to fetch the presigned URL from the backend using the code below.

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const downloadRoutes = require("./routes/downloadRoutes");

const app = express();

app.use("/api/download", downloadRoutes);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 5000");
});
```

routes/downloadRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyID: process.env.AMAZON_ACESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  s3.getSignedUrl(
    "getObject",
    {
      Bucket: "download-hemanta-cv",
      ResponseContentType: "application/pdf",
      Key: "CV_Hemanta_Sundaray.pdf",
    },
    (err, url) => {
      console.log("Error", err, "url", url);
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        res.send(url);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem I am facing is when I paste the URL in chrome I get the following message.
[image]

How can I see the PDF file when I open the URL in the browser?

Comment: Try this `const s3 = new AWS.S3({ signatureVersion: "v4", accessKeyID: ..., secretAccessKey:...  })` , we can pass signatureVersion when initializing the object to sign the request with V4

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 needs signature V4 for requests sent to newer regions. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) is the link to documentation.

> Amazon S3 supports Signature Version 4, a protocol for authenticating
> inbound API requests to AWS services, in all AWS regions. At this
> time, AWS Regions created before January 30, 2014 will continue to
> support the previous protocol, Signature Version 2. Any new Regions
> after January 30, 2014 will support only Signature Version 4 and
> therefore all requests to those Regions must be made with Signature
> Version 4.

To send a signed request via aws sdk, all we need is to set the signatureVersion when initializing the object.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  accessKeyID: process.env.AMAZON_ACESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
});
```

Comment: @hemanta Did this help? if yes, can you please upvote and/or approve the answer?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66810812/9409877