# Unable to load the file by loading the presignedURL in the browser

Tags: amazon-s3

I did the changes as per your suggestion. But I got the following error. My region is set to ap-south-1

[image]

[image]

Comment: its ok to ask clarification on an existing question, rather than posting a new question. This question is more a continuation and for some one looking at just this question, lacks a lot of detail, hence you are getting downvotes :(

Comment: you need `AWS.config.update({ region: "ap-south-1" })` or pass `region: 'ap-south-1'` to s3 object initialization

Comment: Solved. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens when url is signed with a different region than the s3 object.
We can set region globally in SDK

```
AWS.config.update({ region: "ap-south-1" })
```

or pass the region when initializing the S3 Object.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: 'ap-south-1'
})
```